# How do I switch back from location bar to path bar?

Tags: nautilus

I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to switch the graphical path bar (sometimes called a breadcrumb) into a text-based location bar. I expect that hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> again will switch back, but it doesn't. Is this a bug? If not, how do I switch back?

(I don't want to make the change permanent.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While in location bar, try hitting 'esc'.